# How Do I stop resharper from changeing 'base' to 'this'?

Tags: inheritance, resharper-9.0

I have some code similar to this:

```
public void Create(Foo asset)
{
    asset.Status = "Pending";
    base.Create(asset);
}
```

When i do a code cleanup, Resharper changes it to

```
public void Create(Foo asset)
{
    asset.Status = "Pending";
    this.Create(asset);
}
```

This is bad functionality,  how do I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

its because i wasn't overriding and the Create wasn't virtual...

```
public override void Create(Foo asset)
{
    asset.Status = "Pending";
    base.Create(asset);
}
```

this fixes it.